# Does knowing $\phi (n)$ help in prime factorization?

Tags: number-theory

If you know $\phi (n)$ how can you derive the prime factorization of $n$ from this? For example, $\phi(100) = 40$, but how does $40$ help us come to $2^25^2$?

Comment: If as in RSA $n$ is the product of two large primes, $\varphi(n)$ makes finding the factors very easy.

Comment: (on the other hand if you know nothing about $n$ a priori there's not much you can say. for instance $\phi(41) = 40$ also.)

Comment: I imagine you mean this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222125/prime-factorization-knowing-n-and-eulers-function

Comment: So with just $n$ and $\phi(n)$ and not the stipulation that $n=p*q$ this cannot be solved?

Comment: @user3064097 With just $n$ and $\phi(n)$ this can be solved very efficiently regardless of how many factors it has.  See Bill Dubuque's answer in the above link.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{e_i}$ for distinct primes $p_i$ and nonnegative integers $e_i$.  Then $\varphi(n) = \prod_{i=1}^k \varphi(p_i^{e_i}) = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{e_i}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)$.  For any $e_i \geq 2$, we find that $p_i | (\varphi(n),n)$.  In your example, $(\varphi(100),100) = (40,100) = 20$ which is divisible by both $2$ and $5$.

If $n$ is squarefree, you get somewhat less information, $(p_i - 1)|\varphi(n)$, so try to factor $\varphi(n)$, add one to each of its divisors (there are generally more of these than factors) and trial divide $n$ by these.

If $n$ is the product of two distinct primes, $p$ and $q$, then $\varphi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = pq -p -q +1 = n -p -q +1$ which is enough information to find the factorization.  I.e., you know $pq=n$ and $p+q = n+1-\varphi(n)$.  This can be partially extended to three factors, $p$, $q$, and $r$, giving a polynomial whose $pq$, $pr$, and $qr$ terms can be bounded since the roots are all real (i.e., the discriminant is positive).  Not quite as good as a factorization, but may yield a small enough range for sieving to work quickly.

The down side is that if $n$ isn't constructed so as to have a special totient value, the only way to compute $\varphi(n)$ is from $n$'s prime factorization.  Which puts the cart before the horse.

Comment: Can you please elaborate just a little? If we do $100\%40 = 20$, which is divisible by $2$ and $5$, how do we deduce that the prime factorization is $2^25^2$?

Comment: @user30...:  $2$ and $5$ divide 20, so we trial divide 100 by 2, getting $100 = 2*50 = 2^2 * 25$ and then we trial divide this by 5, getting ${} = 2^2 * 5*5 = 2^2 * 5^2$.  So we were lucky that all primes dividing 100 appeared with powers >1 so that they appeared in $\varphi(n)$.  Otherwise, we would construct the list of divisors of $\varphi(100)=40=2^3*5$, getting 1,2,4,8,5,10,20,40, add one to each: 2,3,5,9,6,11,21,41 and trial divide by these (or compute GCDs) hoping to find prime factors of 100 that appear only to the first power.  In all cases, this only reduces the unfactored part.