# Factoring $n = pqr$ given $\phi(n)$

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization, cryptography, totient-function

I know there is a fairly elementary way to factor $n = pq$ (distinct primes) given the value of the totient function, but is there an efficient way to find this if we know $n = pqr$ and we know $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)(r-1)$?

Comment: Yes, see Bill's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222125/prime-factorization-knowing-n-and-eulers-function).

Comment: Yes I mentioned in the question that for n = pq it was very elementary but for n = pqr I can't figure out an efficient algorithm.

Comment: In Bill's reference there is an elementary way described. Have a look.